# Strange optimization result with addcarry on gcc

Tags: c++, gcc, assembly, benchmarking, compiler-optimization

Consider the following code that benchmarks the `addcarry` intrinsic:

```
// Preamble
#include <iostream>

// Addcarry wrapper
template <class C, class T>
C addcarry(C carry, T src0, T src1, T* dst)
{
    unsigned long long int d = 0;
    carry = __builtin_ia32_addcarryx_u64(carry, src0, src1, &d);
    *dst = d;
    return carry;
}

// Main function
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // Initialization
    unsigned long long int n = argc > 1 ? std::stoull(argv[1]) : 1ULL << 31;
    unsigned char carry = 0;
    unsigned long long int src1 = 0;
#ifdef NOSTOULL
    unsigned long long int dst = 0;
#else
    unsigned long long int dst = std::stoull("0");
#endif

    // Computation
    for (unsigned long long int src0 = 0; src0 < n; ++src0) {
        src1 = dst;
#ifdef NOWRAPPER
        carry = __builtin_ia32_addcarryx_u64(carry, src0, src1, &dst);
#else
        carry = addcarry(carry, src0, src1, &dst);
#endif
    }

    // Finalization
    return dst + carry;
}
```

I compile with the following command (where `[]` denote options):

```
[g++6.3.0/g++7.1.0] -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -O3 -g [-DNOSTOULL]
[-DNOWRAPPER] addcarry_loop.cpp -o addcarry_loop -madx
```

And then I execute with:

```
time ./addcarry_loop
```

And I obtain the following real/user times  (over several runs):

```
(1) [-DNOSTOULL] [-DNOWRAPPER] => ~0m2.64s
(2) [          ] [-DNOWRAPPER] => ~0m2.61s
(3) [-DNOSTOULL] [           ] => ~0m2.48s
(4) [          ] [           ] => ~0m1.86s
```

We can note that:

- Options (1) and (2) are statistically similar
- Option (3) (with the wrapper function) is marginally faster than options (1) and (2) (without the wrapper function)
- Option (4) is significantly faster than the other ones

How to explain these results, and in particular the last one (which makes no sense to me). How initializing a variable with `stoull` and wrapping a function can make the code faster?

Note: experiments with other compilers/other architectures are welcome (`adx` instruction set needed).

**EDIT:** Given the commentaries, I updated the code, extracting the loop from the main function:

```
// Preamble
#include <iostream>

// Addcarry wrapper
template <class C, class T>
C addcarry(C carry, T src0, T src1, T* dst)
{
    unsigned long long int d = 0;
    carry = __builtin_ia32_addcarryx_u64(carry, src0, src1, &d);
    *dst = d;
    return carry;
}

// Compute
unsigned long long int compute(unsigned long long int n)
{
    // Initialization
    unsigned char carry = 0;
    unsigned long long int src1 = 0;
#ifdef NOSTOULL
    unsigned long long int dst = 0;
#else
    unsigned long long int dst = std::stoull("0");
#endif

    // Computation
    for (unsigned long long int src0 = 0; src0 < n; ++src0) {
        src1 = dst;
#ifdef NOWRAPPER
        carry = __builtin_ia32_addcarryx_u64(carry, src0, src1, &dst);
#else
        carry = addcarry(carry, src0, src1, &dst);
#endif
    }

    // Finalization
    return dst + carry;
}

// Main function
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    return compute(argc > 1 ? std::stoull(argv[1]) : 1ULL << 31);
}
```

The assembly corresponding to the loop seems a little be different. On the following image, the left side corresponds to empty options `[] []` while the right side corresponds to `[] [-DNOWRAPPER]` (the left side is the "fast" one, the right one is the "slow" one).

[image: Valgrin results]

Comment: When you're saying these things are faster or similar in terms of performance, over how many runs is this? What's the mean and variance in time for those runs, and what kind of statistical test (e.g. t test) are you using to show they're different (what's the resulting p value)? I believe you that there's a performance difference, but you need to prove it, first.

Comment: Even more so than AndyG, I'm skeptical of the benchmarking methodology. Throwing this up on Godbolt's Compiler Explorer and comparing the disassembly, it's pretty clear that `-DNOSTOULL` should create a noticeable improvement. It certainly has a significant effect on the generated assembly. So it coming out to be virtually the same running time with and without seems quite unlikely. (I can confirm, though, that the generated code becomes more optimal *with* the wrapper, which is indeed curious. Not sure why yet. I don't have time to investigate now, even though this has piqued my curiosity.)

Comment: I cannot reproduce your results with g++ 6.3.0. Here, I got the same build with or without `-madx`, and my results are slower than yours: ~3.5s. Maybe if you see the generated asm instructions, you can find the answer (can you post the asm here?).

Comment: @Cody: Why? I've checked the compiled code with compiler explorer, and the main loop compiled the same, no matter of the presence of `-DNOSTOULL` (as it should be, the compiler is not smart enough to optimize away the whole loop).

Comment: One thing you've to watch out for is that GCC tends to disable lots of optimizations for the `main` function, under the assumption that this will never be the bottleneck in real code, since it's only executed once. Looking at the disassembly of exactly what you have here is therefore pretty noisy, so I modified the code slightly to focus on the important bits. I renamed `main`, and took `n` as a parameter so I don't need to initialize it but the compiler still can't optimize around it. As you can see [here](https://godbolt.org/g/QqDVcN), `-DNOSTOULL` *substantially* improves the generated code

Comment: But I may have just answered the question, if you are actually benchmarking this with the code wrapped in a `main` method that GCC is not optimizing. As @geza said, [looking at your code exactly as written](https://godbolt.org/g/71bdNm), there is some difference when `-DNOSTOULL` is added, but the differences are less significant. Godbolt's diff view isn't helpful, and I haven't gone through this line-by-line, but it still looks to me like `-DNOSTOULL` is improving the code. Anyway, maybe rerun the benchmark with the code that does the work in a method named something other than `main`.

Comment: @Cody: the main loop is the same in your examples. You can check it: it starts at .L40 in the stoull, and at .L31 in the without-stoull version. Same instructions, same logic, just a little bit different (registers differ). It should run at the same speed. Btw, its nice to see the c++ "crap". If you replace stoull with strtoll, code becomes much less, and even more optimal (no memory reference in the main loop)

Comment: I just added assembly analysis from Valgrind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot reproduce your results, I've tried gcc 6.3.0, and gcc 7.1.0. Here, all your variants run at the same speed. However, for some reason, your disassembly differs from mine. Looking at your disassembly, it has some strange things. For example, on the left side, at 0x400d7d, there's an unnecessary memory move: it could be moved out after the loop. Certainly, a good programmer could write a better code here (the best code in this case is to remove the loop completely, and apply the mathematical formula for it).

In my opinion, compilers are still not good enough. They becomes better and better (great work compiler developers!), but sometimes they generate code far from optimal.

Here's my last experience: I've written a huffman decoder. Clang generated a code which run at almost half speed than GCC's one. This is a big difference. I've checked disassembly, and clang tried to "merge" two 32-bit variables into 64-bit registers (maybe it tried so hard to avoid using the stack?). I've modified the code little bit, then clang code suddenly became a little bit faster than GCC's one.

When creating such a little loop as yours, every little detail matters. Modifying the code little bit can cause a huge speed difference. And maybe the same compiled code behaves differently on a different processor (Intel/AMD).

**My suggestion is this**: when writing performance sensitive loop, try to put the loop into a separate function. This function should not contain any prologue or epilogue code, just the loop. This way you can help the compiler to optimize better (to use registers as efficiently as possible). My huffman decoder become 20% faster using this technique. I'm not saying that you should stick to this rule 100%, but usually it works for me.